# Magento 2 get attribute values

Tags: php, magento, attributes, magento2

I have created a product attribute in Magento 2 that is a dropdown.
I have given this attribute many options. How can I output all these possible options attached to the attribute code/name? I can only find examples for Magento 1 or those that are assigned to a product. I want to get all the options assigned to the attribute.

This is what I tried before realising it wasnt for Magento 2.

```
<?php
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel(‘eav/entity_attribute’)->getIdByCode(‘catalog_product’,’color’);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel(‘eav/entity_attribute_option_collection’)
    ->setPositionOrder(‘asc’)
    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
    ->setStoreFilter(0)
    ->load();
print_r($collection->getData());
?>
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

you can try below code

```
function getAttrAllOptions() {

$eavConfig = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$alloptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

foreach($alloptions as $option) {
    $label = $option['label'];
    $AllOptionsArr[$label][] = $option['value'];

}

return $AllOptionsArr;
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: any helper/model file.

Comment: Could you post a more detailed answer?

Comment: @zekia, Share you exact need. Based on that only I can suggest.

Comment: Where did you place the code you posted? Did you create a new module? What files did you include in that?

Comment: You can create a helper file in your module where you need the values and then you can use it from there.